# Cannot access the properties inside the Closure object in php 7

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7

I have this in my unit test code:

```
$data = $this->_createSfApiFindMock($cisDataCount);
var_dump($data()); die();
```

output:

```
class Closure#731 (3) {
  public $static =>
  array(4) {
    'cisDataCount' =>
    int(201)
    'cisBillObjectBase' =>
    class stdClass#716 (20) {
      public $unisrv_dcis__TargetMonth__c =>
      string(6) "202301"
      .........
      public $unisrv_dcis__Member__r =>
      class stdClass#717 (1) {
        ...
      }
      public $unisrv_dcis__Contract__r =>
      class stdClass#718 (3) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'cisBillDetailsObjectBase' =>
    array(5) {
      [0] =>
      class stdClass#720 (11) {
        ...
      }
      [1] =>
      class stdClass#722 (11) {
        ...
      }
      [2] =>
      class stdClass#724 (11) {
        ...
      }
      [3] =>
      class stdClass#726 (11) {
        ...
      }
      [4] =>
      class stdClass#728 (13) {
        ...
      }
    }
    'maxDataChunkSize' =>
    int(200)
  }
}
```

How to get access to `cisBillDetailsObjectBase`?

I tried:

```
$cisBillDetailsObjectBase = $data->static['cisBillDetailsObjectBase'];
$data->static();
$data->static;
$data->{"\0Closure\0static"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access to the content of a Closure. A Closure is a function to execute.

Take a look to this simple code:

```php
var_dump(function() { static $a; });
```

Output

```
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["a"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

You cannot access to the internal data of the function because of the scope.

You should **execute** the closure that return something or interact with something else to "export" its data.

Example:

```php
$a = function() { static $a = 2; return $a; };
var_dump($a()); // CALL
```

Output:

```
int(2)
```